# How to append data in to NSMutableArray in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, nsmutablearray

I'm working on an food ordering app currently when I add items into any array, then I need to pass that items to `cartVC` via `CartDataModal` where the `cartArrayDict` is of `NSMutableArray` type. But when I insert the `SelectedDict` the app crashes can anyone help me with this?

Heres my code:

```
var restMenu = [[String:Any]]()

func addTapped(cell: RestaurantItemViewCell)
{
    //get the indexPath for add button click
    let indexPath = self.restTableView.indexPath(for: cell)
     print("the indexPath is", indexPath?.row)

    print("all obj is",restMenu)

    var selectedDict = restMenu[(indexPath?.row)!]
    print("selected dict is",selectedDict)

     selectedDict["ItemQuant"] = cell.itemQuantityLabel.text

    print("selected dict is",selectedDict)


    // Append In Cart Modal
    CartDataModal.shared_Inst.cartArrayDict.insert(selectedDict, at: (indexPath?.row)!)


    print("rest menu is",restMenu)

    restMenu.remove(at: (indexPath?.row)!)
    print("rest menu is",restMenu)

    restMenu.insert(selectedDict, at: (indexPath?.row)!)

    print("restmenu is",restMenu)
}
```

My CartDataModal:

```
class CartDataModal: NSObject {
    static let shared_Inst = CartDataModal()
    var cartArrayDict: [String:Any]!
}
```

from my ViewController i'm getting data From my Restaurant.plist

```
func moveToDetailController(img:UIImage,name:String)
{
    print("the rest name is", name)

    let pathUrl =  Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ResturantFile", ofType: ".plist")
    print("path url is",pathUrl as Any)

    let finalArray = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: pathUrl!)
    print("final Array is",finalArray)

    let restaurantNames = finalArray?.firstObject as? NSDictionary
    print("resturant name is",restaurantNames as Any)


    if let menuDataArray:[[String:Any]] = restaurantNames?.value(forKey: name) as? [[String:Any]]
    {

        print("menu data is",menuDataArray)

    let restVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RestaurantViewController") as! RestaurantViewController

    restVC.tempImg = img
    restVC.tempTitle = name

    restVC.restMenu = menuDataArray

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(restVC, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: If swift `var` means mutable and `let` means immutable. `NSMutableArray` is the objective C data type. for swift use `var cartArrayDict: [String]!` . Here it is array of string (change string to your required type). To append value in array use [append](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1538872-append)

Comment: its not working error

Comment: Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to expected argument type 'String'

Comment: I am totally confused with your code, unable to get what actually you wanted to do and what is that code is for??

Comment: first i get the data for restraunt items , price ,quant from the data recieved from plist then i make a filter for that data to get the corresponding selected restaurant data

Comment: after that i want to get the data which is added to the cart in selectedDict and then i want to pass that data to my CartVC to show that in cartTableView

Comment: i got the data in the selectedDict which i want to pass via CartDataDict shared instance

Comment: cartArrayDict is NSMutableArray and restMenu is [[String : Any]]. you can assign two different data types. Here this making conflict in your code. Correct this.

Comment: i've corrected this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your struct:

```
class CartDataModal: NSObject {

static let shared_Inst = CartDataModal()

var cartArrayDict = [[String: Any]]()

}
```

You need to init array of the dictionary before insert. So You can init in struct or you can init before use according to your use.

Comment: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
now this is the error

Comment: the code worked after giving memory to cartArrayDict